# Windows Vista Programmatically remap user directories

Tags: windows, windows-vista, user-environment

I re-image one of my machines regularly; and have a script that I run after the OS install completes to configure my machine; such that it works how I like.

I happen to have my data on another drive...and I'd like to add code to my script to change the location of the Documents directory from "C:\Users\bryansh\Documents" to "D:\Users\bryansh\Documents".

Does anybody have any insight, before I fire up regmon and really roll up my sleeves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use reparse points http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MoreOnVistaReparsePoints.aspx to redirect My Documents.

Answer (score 1):

[`SHSetFolderPath` Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762247(VS.85).aspx) should help, since [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787939.aspx) article mentions its use for folder redirection by the Group Policy API.